# Will protocol-relative URLs for HREFs perform as well as a relative path?

Tags: relative-path, protocol-relative

Let's say I simply want to link to another page within my site. I can use the following options:

```
<!-- relative path -->
<a href="/order-pizza.html">Order Pizza</a>

<!-- absolute path -->
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/order-pizza.html">Order Pizza</a>

<!-- protocol-relative path -->
<a href="//www.mywebsite.com/order-pizza.html">Order Pizza</a>
```

1. Is there a difference in response time when comparing protocol-relative to relative?
2. Are there any drawbacks when using protocol-relative paths with HREFs?

Answer (score 1):

Relative, absolute, or protocol relative URLs are *browser* features.
The browser combines the new URL with the page URL to build a complete URL to send a request to.

It has no effect on the network.

Comment: Okay, since the browser changes protocol-relative paths to absolute there is no difference in performance. Also no difference in performance with absolute versus relative since it's a browser thing, not server, correct? What about drawbacks of using protocol-relative paths in HREFs? Joose de Valk mentions it is a bad idea using them within links. Is that so and what issues will arise besides duplicate content?

Comment: @AaronKahlhamer: Where does he mention that? I'm not aware of any such issues.